# How do I stop hg child process when using hglib

Tags: python, mercurial, hglib

I have a Python application in Mercurial. In the application I found the need to display from which commit it is currently running. The best solution I have found so far is to make use of `hglib`. I have a module which looks like this:

```
def _get_version():
    import hglib
    repo = hglib.open()
    [p] = repo.parents()
    return p[1]

version = _get_version()
```

This uses `hglib` to find the used version and stores the result in a variable, which I can use for the entire time the service remains running.

My problem now is that this leaves a `hg` child process running, which is useless to me, since as soon as this module is done initializing, I don't need to use `hglib` anymore.

I would have expected the child process to be shut down during garbage collection once my reference to the repository instance goes out of scope. But apparently that is not how it works.

When reading the `hglib` documentation I didn't find any documentation on how to get the child process shut down.

What is the preferred method to get the `hg` child process shut down once I am done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat repo sort of like a file. Either call repo.close() when you're done or use it inside a with:

```
def _get_version():
    import hglib
    with hglib.open() as repo:
        [p] = repo.parents()
    return p[1]

version = _get_version()
```